# pandas: create pivot table by two different dimensions?

Tags: python, pandas

I am a pandas newbie. I have a dataframe of examinations taken by sponsor and company:

```
import pandas pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'sponsor': ['A71991', 'A71991', 'A71991', 'A81001', 'A81001'],
  'sponsor_class': ['Industry', 'Industry', 'Industry', 'NIH', 'NIH'],
  'year': [2012, 2013, 2013, 2012, 2013],
  'passed': [True, False, True, True, True],
})
```

Now I want to output a CSV file with a row for each sponsor and its class, and columns for the pass and total rates by year:

```
sponsor,sponsor_class,2012_total,2012_passed,2013_total,2013_passed
A71991,Industry,1,1,2,1
A81001,NIH,1,1,1,1
```

How do I get from `df` to this restructured dataframe? I think I need to group by `sponsor` and `sponsor_class`, and then pivot out the total count, and the count for which `passed` is `True` by year, and then flatten those columns. (I know I end with `pd.write_csv(mydf)`.)

I've tried starting with this:

```
df_g = df.groupby(['sponsor', 'sponsor_class', 'year', 'passed'])
```

But that gives me an empty dataframe.

I think I need a pivot table somewhere to pivot out the year and pass status... but I do not know where to start.

**UPDATE**: Getting somewhere:

```
df_g = df_completed.pivot_table(index=['lead_sponsor', 'lead_sponsor_class'], 
                                columns='year', 
                                aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
df_g[['passed']]
```

Now I need to work out (1) how to get the count of all rows as well as just the `passed`, and (2) how to un-nest the columns for a CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# set index to prep for unstack
df1 = df.set_index(['sponsor', 'sponsor_class', 'year']).astype(int)

# groupby all the stuff in the index
gb = df1.groupby(level=[0, 1, 2]).passed

# use agg to get sum and count    
# swaplevel and sort_index to get stuff sorted out
df2 = gb.agg({'passed': 'sum', 'total': 'count'}) \
          .unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1)

# collapse multiindex into index
df2.columns = df2.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: '{}_{}'.format(*x))

print df2.reset_index().to_csv(index=None)


sponsor,sponsor_class,2012_passed,2012_total,2013_passed,2013_total
A71991,Industry,1,1,1,2
A81001,NIH,1,1,1,1
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see how to do it in quite a few steps:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
df['total'] = df['passed'].astype(int)
ldf = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['sponsor','sponsor_class'],columns='year',
                     values=['total'],aggfunc=len) # total counts
rdf = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['sponsor','sponsor_class'],columns='year',
                     values=['total'],aggfunc=np.sum) # number passed 
cdf = pd.concat([ldf,rdf],axis=1) # combine horizontally
cdf.columns = cdf.columns.get_level_values(0) # flatten index
cdf.reset_index(inplace=True)
columns = ['sponsor','sponsor_class']
yrs = sorted(df['year'].unique())
columns.extend(['{}_total'.format(yr) for yr in yrs])
columns.extend(['{}_passed'.format(yr) for yr in yrs])
cdf.columns = columns
```

Result:

```
>>> cdf
  sponsor sponsor_class  2012_total  2013_total  2012_passed  2013_passed
0  A71991      Industry           1           2            1            1
1  A81001           NIH           1           1            1            1
```

Finally:

```
cdf.to_csv('/path/to/file.csv',index=False)
```